Open file in Chrome Tab
I am trying to figure out a Autohot key 2.0 script that will do the following:-

I'll mouse click a *.pdf file or any other compatible file association.
Press a Hotkey (placed in Ahk 2.0 script) to open this *.pdf into a new Tab in an already existing Chrome window.

So far I have this (AHk 2.0 script):
>!l::           ;;  RAlt + L

{  
    Var = % Explorer_GetSelection( )   
    Run "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --newtab" 
  %Var%   
Return  
}

And I get the error:

Error: var not recognized

I guess I have to declare Var as a Char first?

You guess? Have you just tried declaring a var? That seems pretty simple to test.

Thank you so much
